# angular set a variable accessible to any scope

Tags: angularjs

I am creating an app with Angular. There is a form in the app for a user to enter a string. When a user enters a string this calls a function using ng-submit:

```
ng-model="input1" ng-submit="update()"
```

Within the update function I can then access the value of input1 using

```
$scope.input1
```

What I would like to do is allow that value to be accessible outside of just the scope of the update function, so that it can be called by anything else within the angular app.

Ideally, I would like to be able to update thing1:

```
var app = angular.module('app1, []);
var thing1 = "value from input"
```

I've been through the documentation and am thinking maybe what I need to do is set an app.value, so:

```
var app = angular.module('app1, []);
app.value('thing1', "value from input")
```

Then in the submit function set the value of thing1 so that it updates the app.value, but that isn't working.

I'm not sure how I can do this. Any thoughts?

Comment: maybe $root.input1 ?

Comment: You should use angular services to share data between controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I created a service as follows:

```
app.service('thing', function(){
var string1 = '123'
return{
 getString: function(){
  return string1;
  }
 setString: function(value){
 string1 = value;
}
```

Then within the controller I add the thing service:

```
app.controller('myController', function(thing){
controller code
});
```

I can put a value into the 'thing' service from any scope by using:

```
thing.setString($scope.valueIwantToSet)
```

Or get a value from any scope by using:

```
$scope.variableIwantToUse = thing.getString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a service or value (as you surmised).  This is the *angular-ish* way to do what you desire.

```
.service( 'appService', function(){
    var srvc = {};
    srvc.input1 = 'foo'

    return srvc
}

.value( 'input1', { data: 'foo' })
```

*If you use a value, then you need to use an object as strings and numbers are immutable.  You might consider a `values` value where you store multiple values if you go that route.*

Then you inject that where you need access to it:

```
.controller( 'SomeController', function( $scope, appService ){
     $scope.doSomething = function(){ appService.input1 = 'bar' }
})

.controller( 'AnotherController', function ($scope, $q, appService ){
     $scope.myInput = appService.input1
})
```

Answer (score -2):

I far as I undestant you need to create something like a global variable. Try to use `$rootScope`. This is a parent scope for all the other scopes. You can inject and access it in any controller, so you will be able to read/write your value. Here is the example.

```
function Controller1($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.someVar = "Some value"; 
}

function Controller2($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.someVar2 = $rootScope.someVar;
    $rootScope.someVar = "Some new value";
}
```

You just inject the `$rootScope` into some controller, set the value and then inject this into the other and just read the value.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This then pollutes the *global* ng-scope and makes it implicitly available to everything in the app. OP should use an explicit request for something like this via a service.

Comment: a services isn't always required/desired. There are times when you want all your controllers and their scopes to have access to a variable, and injecting a service and binding it to the scope every time is a bit more trouble than it's worth. 
OP just needs to be aware of the consequences of something being bound to $rootScope and being accessible everywhere (including inheritence on child scopes, etc).
This answer could be improved though, it doesn't show good usage

Comment: Considering that most ng1.x is moving away from the whole $scope paradigm and ng2 doesn't even have it, I would still advise against this other than in the most *extreme* cases.  If injecting everywhere is a pain, use a mixin or subclass a base controller.  There are plenty of other programming paradigms that should be considered before this.